# How to fetch from the sql table with flask/python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to implement the search

sql table

```
id,name,product
1,a,Books
2,b,Books
3,c,Balls,Books,Pen
4,d,Balls,Pen
```

Fetching from `id` field which is working fine

```
if (id): 
         cursor.execute("select * from books where id = %s", [id])
         conn = cursor.fetchall()
```

How to fetch from the `product` field dynamically

```
if (product): 
         cursor.execute("select * from books where product like ('Books')
         conn = cursor.fetchall()
```

This will print all the 4 rows since Books contain all the rows

```
if (product): 
         cursor.execute("select * from books where product like ('Balls','Pen')
         conn = cursor.fetchall()
```

This will print 3rd and 4th row as 3 and 4 have Balls and Pen. After like column it may vary to any number of fields, how to populate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy, just Use the table name you have created in model add objects and call method `all()` it's done.

Example:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = Student.objects.all()
        return render('index.html', data)
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: My question is how to `("select * from books where product like ('Balls','Pen')`, the Balls, Pen are having 2 variables, how to add dynamically if three comes `("select * from books where product like ('Balls','Pen','Books')`